# Relative & absolute Positioning in CSS : Is it possible to create a "punched-out" effect?

Tags: css

I've got an colored background and another element which is layed over that background. Done by using CSS-positioning.

[image: Absolute positioned element in front.]

My idea is to make the area which is covered by the lorem ipsum-text basically to "disappear". So that the background-orange and -cornsilk come through.

One could say:

The absolute positioned element shall look like some board with the chars "punched out". Hold above some background.

Is that possible with CSS?

UPDATE

Here's the code:

```js
(function(selector, horizontalOffset, verticalOffset) {
  var items = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  items = Array.prototype.slice.call(items);

  items.forEach(function(item) {
    // Every time the pointer moves over the element the 
    //  CSS-rule in overwritten with new values for 
    //  top and left.
    item.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
      let countCssRules = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules.length;
      let newRule = selector +
        ':hover:after { display: block; ' + 
                       'left: ' + (e.offsetX + horizontalOffset) + 'px; ' +
                       'top: ' +  (e.offsetY + verticalOffset) + 'px; }';
      
      document.styleSheets[0].insertRule(newRule, countCssRules);
    });
  });
})('.tooltip-item', 10, 5);
```

```css
.wrap {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  font-family: georgia, serif;
  background-color: cornsilk;
}

div.tooltip-item {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 450px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 60px 10px;
}

.tooltip-item {
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip-item:after {
  content: attr(data-message);
  position: absolute;
  left: 105%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: none;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  background-color: rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.6);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}

div.tooltip-item:after {
  background-color: cyan;
  color: #ff14ec;
  font-weight: 800;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 9px #969696;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="tooltip-item" data-message="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit."></div>
</div>
```

What I want is the colors (currently violet) behind the cyan tooltip-box to come through.

I've found these picture (the first one at the very top) showing want I mean: 
http://flyingmeat.com/acorn/docs/creating_pressed_text.html

Comment: can you show an example picture of what you want  ?

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Have added the code and further explanations.

Comment: You have to hover over the orange div !

Comment: i really don't understand what you want :) . the violet is the color of the text, cyan is the bgcolor of the `tooltip-item:after` . what do you mean by : `What I want is the colors (currently violet) behind the cyan tooltip-box to come through.` the violet is not behind the tooltibox

Comment: I mean something like here: http://flyingmeat.com/acorn/docs/creating_pressed_text.html The picture with "Puget Sound". The image with the sky has become the inner filling of the text. It's done with some picture-processing software. My question is: Can I archieve somehing like that with CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use something like this :

```css
p {
   
   background: url("http://beerhold.it/579/300") no-repeat;
   -webkit-background-clip: text;
   background-clip: text;
   color:transparent;
   font-size:40px;
   font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<p>
LOREM IPSUM I AM A TEST
</p>
```

but `background-clip:text;` is not supported in IE . see more here [background-clip CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip)